# How to setup different roles per application?

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3

we plan on using IdentityServer for our single sign on. we have multiple applications with users having different roles per application. it's not clear to me. how do we set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do emit application specific claims you currently need to implement a claims provider.

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/configuration/serviceFactory.html

In v2 this will be even easier since the user service will know more client details.